# Printing Specific Pattern using for Loop in Java

Tags: java, function, loops, for-loop, iteration

i have to print specific   pattern using Java for loop . Input will be 4 characters   eg.

```
    a, b , c, d
```

now what i have to print is

```
    aaaa
    aaab
    aaac
    aaad
    aaba
    abbb
    aabc
```

And so on..  i have tried   some `pyramids codes in java` and  understand to code `nested for loops` , but really getting no idea how to print this ,  Please guide me how i can achieve this .  Thank You

Comment: Show effort -> ask question -> get an answer.

Comment: Look at the bright side: if you System.out.println() those one by one, it's only 256 lines. Totally doable.

Comment: @whoAmI if i m not getting idea to do it then should  i paste  irreverent codes?

Comment: @Sikander if you want us to write code for you - it won't happen. If you want us to teach you Java - also, not gonna happen. If you ask a specific question - we will try very hard to help you!

Comment: @whoAmI: he just ask to `guide` him :)

Comment: sir i never asked to code , anyways ..

Comment: @Sikander so are you having trouble with the actual printing?

Comment: @SamIam i commented it for  whoami, yes  i do have idea to loop through as i mentioned in my question , specific pattern is repeated to no of inputs that was confusing point .

Comment: @Sikander i've added another section to my answer to address that.

Answer (score 1):

Count from 0 to n<sup>n</sup>-1, where `n` is the number of characters. For each count value, determine its base-n representation. Pad to the left with zeroes up to width `n`. Use each digit as an index into the characters. Print.

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely must use loops, you can nest some loops

```
for(char c1 = 'a'; c1<= 'd'; c1++)
{
    for(char c2 = 'a'; c2<= 'd'; c2++)
    {
        for(char c3 = 'a'; c3<= 'd'; c3++)
        {
            for(char c4 = 'a'; c4<= 'd'; c4++)
            {
                //print some combination of c1, c2, c3, and c4
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

If your inputs aren't contiguous `char`s, than your loops might look like

```
char[] inputs
//initialize inputs
for(int i1 = 0; i1 < inputs.length; i++)
{
    char c1 = inputs[i1];
    ...
}
```